# UINavigationController pushViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

the view controller that is pushed onto the stack cannot be an instance of tab bar controller and it must not already be on the navigation stack.

I want to know how could I discover if the view controller that I'm about to push onto the stack is already in stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if its `navigationController` property is `nil`.

Comment: but it might be not nil and the viewcontroller isn't already pushed.

Comment: consider this case :
- if the navigationcontroller has some another viewcontrolles on its stack but the myviewcontroller that I want to check if it's already on stack or not is not on stack.
- you want me to check if it's not nil then myviewcontroller is already pushed, which won't be accurate.

Comment: You want to look at the navigationController property of the view controller that is (or is not) on the stack, e.g., myNewConroller.navigationController. As long as you haven't pushed it onto a navigation controller, it should be nil (even if your nav controller has other controllers on it). Not 100% sure if this gets set back to nil after you pop it though. And I think if can get set if you modally present it from a controller that is on a nav stack.

Comment: I think your answer is the best, but what if the viewcontroller that we are talking about was UITableViewController which doesn't have navigation controller property.

Comment: All UIViewControllers have a navigationController property: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW44

Answer (score 3):

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
for (UIViewController* controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[MapViewViewController class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Cool");
    }

}
```

Comment: childViewControllers method dont exists for navigation controllers

Comment: I expected it should work, but it doesn't.
and one more thing, the for loop will cause to repeat executing the task in case of there are many viewcontrollers on stack.

Comment: that is what it is supposed to do.. check for every view controller in the stack.. and did you change the childViewControllers to viewControllers..? I edited my answer above.

Comment: this works perfectly fine for me.. I have even tested it on my simulator.. I re wrote the code.. (MapViewViewController is my class).

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Use the `self.navigationController.viewControllers` array to reference the controller that's already on the nav controller's stack.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I don't want to pop it, I want to check if it's already on stack or it's not.

Comment: then you need to use self.navigationController.viewControllers property and loop through it

Answer (score 0):

You can use flags. Set a flag when you push the viewcontroller first time. Reset it if you pop to this view controller. Check the flag value before pushing. If set, it is already in stack, so don't push again. else, not in stack, so push it.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I'm asking about another way, like an API or something like that.

Comment: You are most welcome. I also didn't find any API kind-of thing .. Rather, flags seems easy.